# How to trigger Kafka Window change at EOD?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a change where in we are using hopping windows in Kafka. Our requirement is realtime updates so we will have to use onWindowUpdate(). But we also want the window(24 hours) switch at EOD. Can we do it with a configuration ? Or a simple EOD trigger?

We can only think of creating dummy events at EOD for all the keys and passing it downstream to refresh/change the window? Any elegant solution?